# Using a Laplace transform to figure something out in a DC circuit

Tags: math, laplace-transform

When would you use a Laplace transform to figure something out about a circuit? Does the circuit have to have capacitors?

Answer (score 5):

The LaPlace transform isn't really used in DC analysis of circuits.  Typically, you would just use your standard "Circuits 101" tools to analyze the DC properties of a circuit.  These are:

- Kirchhoff's Current Law (Nodal Analysis)
- Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (Loop Analysis)
- Thevenin's (or Norton's) Theorem

In DC, capacitors are treated as open circuits (hence why they are also known "DC blockers") and inductors are treated as close circuits (or dead shorts).

LaPlace transforms are used in both frequency and transient analysis.  They replace the more complex method of solving differential equations, or using convolution to determine the response of a circuit to an input.

Transient analysis builds upon the basic DC analysis, but determines what the circuit will do in response to a transient (a step input, an impulse, a ramp, etc).

Frequency analysis then builds upon the transient analysis to determine the response of a circuit to periodic signals (sine wave, square wave, triangle waves, as an example).

LaPlace analysis is frequently used in

- Filter design (creating a circuit with specific frequency responses)
- Controls (forcing a system or circuit to react with particular transient and frequency responses).
- Higher level analysis of most electrical engineer (power, communications, electromagnetics,etc).

Comment: So if you put a capacitor in a DC circuit, it will act as an open circuit, and nothing will work?

Comment: Assuming that the circuit is ONLY DC, and there are no transients (switches closing or opening, signal inputs, etc).  DC analysis is best though of as an analogy to statics in mechanical engineering.  Nothing in your circuit is moving or changing, and it is at an equilibrium. AC analysis is when you add some sort of dynamic input to your system.  Once you add a dynamic to the system, then you will have you use LaPlace analysis to determine what the circuit will do over time.

Comment: What if the voltage source comes from an AC adaptor and it's going into a voltage regulator with capacitors connected to it? Why would a voltage regulator need capacitors if the voltage is DC?

Comment: You typically find capacitors on voltage regulators and next to chips because DC is an ideal (never happens!).  In real life, there is always noise on the supply lines, and the capacitors form a filter (low-pass) with a large RC time constant (and a really low bandwidth).  This means that it essentially forms a filter that blocks everything above a really small frequency (0.1 Hz, 0.001 Hz, etc).  This means that your circuit that you are supplying only "sees" DC, and none of the transient noise from other sources.

Comment: What if there was no noise? Would it turn into an open circuit?

Comment: Correct.  The capacitor between the voltage supply and ground is an open circuit when there are no transients.

Comment: Then does that mean that the correct functioning of a circuit with a capacitor relies on there being noise?

Comment: It depends on the circuit.  For this example, in order for the capacitor to really do anything, there has to be some transient component to the voltage source.  Basically, capacitors and inductors respond to time-varying signals.  Noise is a type of time-varying signal.

Comment: I would rather say that correct functioning of the real circuit (with noise and transients) relies on there being a capacitor. :) Also, without any capacitors a real voltage regulator may oscillate or do some other strange things.

Comment: @200ok404notfound I am confused by your comment about how the correct function relies on their being noise. This makes no sense. In an ideal world when your voltage line is pure DC the capacitors will act as if they just weren't there. It will still function though.